# Java error handling, what's the correct way to handle this?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

What's in java the correct method to handle method params/inner errors?

All the three methods do the same thing, with a little difference in the second one where exception also have a "caused by" section.

Please not that in the third method, the return must be repeated every time i want to exit from it.

Consider also that exception handling is quite expensive in java (i've read this somewhere).

Thanks!!

```
public static String method(String arg) {
  block: {
    if (arg == null) {
      logger.error("arg is null");
      break block;
    }
    try {
      ...  
      return "ok";
    } catch (Exception e)
      logger.error("help!", e);
    }
  }
  return "ko";
}

public static String method(String arg) {
  try {
    if (arg == null) {
      throw new Exception("arg is null");
    }
    ...
    return "ok";
  } catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("help!", e);
    return "ko";
  }
}

public static String method(String arg) {
  String result = "ko";
  if (arg == null) {
    logger.error("arg is null");
    return result;
  }
  try {
    ..
    result = "ok";
  } catch(Exception e) {
    logger.error("help!", e);
  }
  return result;
}
```

EDIT:
Also, in the second method, you can differentiate inner method errors by using RuntimeException (or a custom one), bad idea?

Comment: It's senseless to throw an exception and catch it in the same method, a few lines away.  Otherwise, the choice between the first and third schemes is one of personal preference (along with other design pressures).

Comment: I'd let the method throw the exception

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the "right" way is any of these 3.

Java has an exception just for invalid parameters, called [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html), which is actually a [RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html), so you don't declare it. The idea is that if you provide an illegal argument, this is a bug in the caller side, so the caller must catch and deal with the exception.

When your method returns a valid result for an "illegal" argument, IMO, your argument is not really illegal, so there shouldn't be an exception and then there's nothing to recover from. And so, your code should look like

```
    public static String method(String arg) {
        return arg==null?"ko":"ok";
    }
```

No exceptions here.

Now, if a null argument is something exceptional that you have to deal with, I think the right approach is to treat it in the caller side. In the JDK, you'll find examples of both explicit and implicit invalid argument exceptions, for example:

Explicit

```
 * @param      s   the string to be parsed.
 * @return     a {@code Double} object holding the value
 *             represented by the {@code String} argument.
 * @throws     NumberFormatException  if the string does not contain a
 *             parsable number.
 */
public static Double valueOf(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    return new Double(FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(s).doubleValue());
}
```

Implicit

```
 * @param   uri
 *          the URI to convert
 *
 * @return  the resulting {@code Path}
 *
 * @throws  IllegalArgumentException
 *          if preconditions on the {@code uri} parameter do not hold. The
 *          format of the URI is provider specific.
   (...)
 */
public static Path get(URI uri) {
    String scheme =  uri.getScheme();
    if (scheme == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing scheme");
    (...)
```

I think the whole idea here is

1. if a null arg is an exceptional situation, not expected by your method, then it's a bug and you must recover from it outside the called method. If the called method can deal with the null arg (returning for example some valid value such as "ko") then it's not an exceptional situation, but just a valid argument for which there's a valid result, so no exceptions are needed here.
2. otherwise, you must throw an exception (explicit or not) and let the caller deal with it

That's what I think.

Answer (score 0):

Up for the first one, cause it's more elegant, but third one is more clear to read and less error prone imho.

Comment: This is just based on opinion. Besides that, labels should be avoided at all costs; they are mainly included to support automatic code generation.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the one that is easiest to read. Remember that code is written once and read many times.

The third one is the most easiest to read.

Another rule which is pretty good. One entry one exist for every method.
It is preferable to only use one return statement.

The reason is that it is easier for the next reader to understand what the thought is with the code.

More about this kinds of issue, you can read about in Clean Code [http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)

Suggestion for one entry-exist solution:

```
public static String method(String arg) {
    String outString = "ko";
    try {
        if (arg != null) {
            outString = "ok";
        } else {
            logger.debug("arg is null");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Help!", e);
    }
    return outString;
}
```

Comment: so you are telling me that while the third one is easier to read, the first one accomplish to the "one entry/one exit" rule than it's the preferable way to follow?

Comment: Nither one of them follow one entry one exist -rule.

I would have codit something like this.

I tried to add the code in the comment. But couldn't. So I updated my response with the new example.

Comment: you missed a return in you else clause, cause it will continue execution neverless.

Comment: @Seby. I'm not sure that I agree with you. The else should not have any return statement. The entire idea behind one-entry-one-exist, is that you should only have one exist. That is the return statement last in the method.

And my suggestion have that. The outString does not have to be set in the else. Since that string already have the negative value in it. 
So if you run all those four cases in the in the "same" JUnit test. Then you will see that they do the same thing. Also the else will only be run when arg is null.